# Need help understanding concurrent mergesort

Tags: go, concurrency, mergesort

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to concurrency and I'm looking at concurrent mergesorting in go.

I saw another question about someone trying to implement the same thing. The answer contained the code for the for ok1 || ok2 at the bottom of the merge function. I don't understand whats going on, would anyone be able to give a detailed explanation of the merge function?

Thanks. Code below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func merge(a []int, ch chan int) {
    //     defer close(ch)
    if len(a) == 0 {
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    if len(a) == 1 {
        ch <- a[0]
        close(ch)
        return
    }

    mid := len(a) / 2

    ch1 := make(chan int)
    go merge(a[:mid], ch1)

    ch2 := make(chan int)
    go merge(a[mid:], ch2)

    v1, ok1 := <-ch1
    v2, ok2 := <-ch2

    for ok1 || ok2 {
        if (ok1 && ok2 && v1 < v2) || (ok1 && !ok2) {
            fmt.Printf("v1 = %v, ch = %v", v1, ch)
            ch <- v1
            v1, ok1 = <-ch1
        } else if (ok1 && ok2 && v1 >= v2) || (!ok1 && ok2) {
            ch <- v2
            v2, ok2 = <-ch2
            fmt.Printf("v2 = %v, ch = %v", v2, ch)
        }
    }
    close(ch)
}

func Merge(a []int) (sorted []int) {
    ch := make(chan int)
    go merge(a, ch)

    for v := range ch {
        sorted = append(sorted, v)
    }
    return
}

func generateSlice(size int) []int {

    slice := make([]int, size)
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        slice[i] = rand.Intn(999) - rand.Intn(999)
    }
    return slice
}

func main() {
    slice := generateSlice(10)
    start := time.Now()
    sorted := Merge(slice)
    fmt.Printf("Time taken to sort: %v, sorted: %v", time.Since(start), sorted)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ok1` and `ok2` are the second returns from a pair of channel reads, which will be `false` iff the channel being read from is empty and closed (there are no more values and none more coming). In that event, the value read will be the zero value for the channel's type, so it shouldn't be treated as a "real" value. As long as one or the other is true, there are still values to process, which is why it's used for the loop.

https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/4

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just a few other quick questions, is the second if loop assigning the channel to the first a value, if it does how does it iterate through the array values.  Also in the loop when the v1/v2 is sent to ch, is it received in the Merge function in the for loop?

Comment: I'm not sure which code you're referring to as "the second if loop", but I don't see any channel assignments outside of where the channels are created, only sends/receives. To your second question, yes, it's being received by `Merge`.

Comment: I'm referring to if len(a) ==1 near the top of merge func. I just don't understand how the channel receives the array values. In the for loop v1 sends to channel ch to be received in Merge then v1 receives from ch1 again, but how does ch1 iterate to the next array value?

Comment: Nothing iterates the array values. The beginning of `merge` (having two functions with the same name except for capitalization makes this code hard to discuss) keeps splitting the array it gets in half and calling itself recursively, concurrently.

Comment: Ok, without this if statement ```len(a) == 1 { ch <- a[0] close(ch) return }``` the program runs but nothing happens. Is that because the channel ch is waiting to receive in the other function ```Merge``` and without the send it blocks?